# Ocaml where and how to define a function that only returns a value

Tags: function, ocaml

I have the following code

```
let mymain origarg = 
  let results = helperfunc origarg in 
  (results, origarg)

let rec helperfunc newarg = 
  match newarg with
  | [] -> []
  | h::t -> h :: helperfunc (someotherfunc t origarg)
```

`origarg` is a list. How do I write a function that can supply the unmodified `origarg` to my helperfunc on every recursive call?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want `helperfunc` to have two arguments? So then one of them will always be origarg, and the other will vary through the recursion.

If this is what you want, you need to define `helperfunc` to take two arguments. Your definition has just one argument. You want something like this:

```
let rec helperfunc arg_1 arg_2 = ...
```

When you call `helperfunc` recursively, you need to supply both arguments. The first argument will be `arg_1`. The second argument will be whatever else you want to pass to the recursive invocation.

Comment: The argument to helperfunc is a tuple of the form (a, b) and it must stay that way. I want to use another value inside helperfunc which is originally given to mymain. Is there a way I can define a function that only supplies a value and can be called anywhere?

Comment: The argument to `helperfunc` in the code you give is definitely not a tuple. It's a list. I guess I just don't understand your question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a helper function that closes over `origarg`.

First of all, you did not define `someotherfunc`, here is one that satisfies the type signature:

```
(* just to match the expected type *)
let someotherfunc x y = x @ y
```

Then, you embed the definition for `helperfunc` in another function:

```
let make_helperfunc origarg =
  let rec helperfunc newarg = match newarg with
    | [] -> []
    | h::t -> h::helperfunc (someotherfunc t origarg)
  in helperfunc
```

Every time you call `make_helperfunc` with a given `origarg`, that function builds another function, the local recursive `helperfunc` function, which captures in its lexical environment the `origarg` variable. The returned value is called a *closure*.

In your main function, you need to first build such a closure using `origarg`, and call it:

```
let mymain origarg =
  let helper = make_helperfunc origarg in
  let results = helper origarg in (results, origarg)
```

Here the argument to `helper` is also `origarg`, but this is just a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

If you nest the functions then origarg remains in scope like this:

```
let mymain origarg = 
  let rec helperfunc newarg = 
    match newarg with
    | [] -> []
    | h::t -> h :: helperfunc (someotherfunc t origarg)
  in
  let results = helperfunc origarg in 
  (results, origarg)
```